# User management with no email

Tags: user, emails, registration

We are building a Joomla 3.x component for school management where each student will have a user account to login and manage their dashboards.

The problem is not all students will have email address and in Joomla email is mandatory for a user.

I am looking for a decent way how to bypass this without hacking any core functionality.

Comment: Hahaha, exact same problem here. We need a school module. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to do this with a user plugin that can both remove the unnecessary field from the form and fill the email in automatically with something autogenerated to get past the requirement.

[Joomla Registration: Remove unneeded fields](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/7392/joomla-registration-remove-unneeded-fields) should help you with the basics of creating a user plugin and removing the email fields.

Likewise, if you use my answer to that question, you can add in an automated email address in `onUserBeforeSave` which should get the record past the model's validation and store the user "without" an email.