# Joomla User Registration Form Plugin not working - simple registration (PlgUserSimpleRegistration)

Tags: plugin, user, registration

I try to have the plugin working to have a email/password only on the registration form.
[Joomla Registration: Remove unneeded fields](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/7392/joomla-registration-remove-unneeded-fields)

I install the plugin correctly with XML below:

```
<extension version="3.1" type="plugin" group="user">
    <name>plg_simple_registration</name>
    <description>PLG_SIMPLE_REGISTRATION_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="SimpleRegistration">PlgUserSimpleRegistration.php</filename>
    </files>
```

But, the plugin is enabled in the backend but never launched.
-> Is it about the group?

I try the have the form name printed but it never show

```
    class PlgUserSimpleRegistration extends JPlugin
{
    function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
    {
        $name = $form->getName();
        echo "<h2>Simple Registration" .  $name . "</h2>";
```

I try another plugin 'Regauth' and it works great.
I don't see any issue on the SimpleRegistration plugin.

Comment: Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the answer

```
class PlgUserSimpleRegistration extends JPlugin
```

change "Plg" with "plg"

```
class plgUserSimpleRegistration extends JPlugin
```

It's working now

Comment: This appears to be just another way that Joomla branches away from [PHP's PSR coding standards](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#:~:text=Class%20names%20MUST,.)  Or is this perhaps the symptom of something else that is incorrect in your project?

Comment: I think your XMLIs not Joomla like.Here you see a Camelcase Name in Joomla: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/672ee343a22520d6a230c27269b00993eeea0c49/plugins/user/profile/profile.php#L26. Here is the line in XML   <filename plugin="profile">profile.php</filename> (https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/672ee343a22520d6a230c27269b00993eeea0c49/plugins/user/profile/profile.xml#L13)

Comment: @Jeremy Sanglier - as in the above comments, you had incorrectly given the name of the plugin in the XML file (missing the plugin group). It should be: `<name>plg_user_simpleregistration</name>` and the plugin class name should be: `class PlgUserSimpleregistration`